# sqlite dump does not do anything

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite3 application that laying in `D:\` to make dump of database (`documents.db3`) that laying in `D:\`.

But after printing command `documents.db3 .dump > doc.sql` nothing happens

```
SQLite version 3.5.4
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite > documents.db3 .dump >doc.sql
    ...>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just writing the file name works only when you are executing `sqlite3´ from your OS's shell.

When you are inside the [command-line line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html), you have to use commands understood by it:

```
D:\> sqlite3
SQLite version 3.5.4
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .open documents.db3
sqlite> .output dump.sql
sqlite> .dump
sqlite> .exit
```

And consider [upgrading](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) your SQLite; version 3.5.4 is horribly outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Do it from the command line not inside the interactive shell.

$ sqlite3 documents.db3 .dump > dump.sql